# Postgres COPY FORCE_NOT_NULL option not recognized

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I'm trying to import a CSV file into Postgres 9.2 using the COPY command. For all columns, empty strings in the CSV must be interpreted as NULL with the exception of one column.

I believe [FORCE_NOT_NULL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) option is meant to allow this, but when I enter the following command:

```
COPY migr_escolas  from 'C:\escolas.csv' 
     WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER FORCE_NOT_NULL;
```

I get the following message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error next to "FORCE_NOT_NULL" 
LINE 16: ...om 'C:\escolas.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER FORCE_NOT_...
```

Is FORCE_NOT_NULL really supported? If so what's the syntax?

**System Info:**

```
"PostgreSQL 9.2.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit"
Windows 7 64 bits
```

Comment: FORCE_NOT_NULL needs a (non empty) comma list of column names after it. It should also be written **without the underscores** : `FORCE NOT NULL col1, col2, ...`

Comment: Thanks.... can't belive it was the underscores...

Answer (score 9):

As pointed by joop's comment above, one should use FORCE NOT NULL and not FORCE_NOT_NULL.